# Facebook signout after 15 minutes

Tags: php, facebook, session

I have kept user login though facebook on my site.

Is it possible that I can make user logout after 15 minutes from his facebook account, after he logged in?

scenario is like this:

login.php:

user logins using facbook JS SDK. On successful login

redirect to start.php through ajax call.

on start.php I have user facebook ID.

I want to perform logout(session close) after 15minutes or user close the browser

I think setInterval() is only solution right?

Can I use `FB.logout()` in start.php directly?

Comment: You want to do it at client-side? I can think of `setInterval()` and re-direct to Facebook logout URL. You might want to try

Answer (score 0):

You can do by javascript with setTimeout() function and use Facebook javascript api,

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout/

```
setTimeout(function(){
    FB.logout(function(response) {
      // user is now logged out
    });
}, 900000);
```

In php, you can get facebook logouturl in SDK and check this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLogoutUrl/ for reference

Comment: please see my update. Can I call `setTimeout()` on start.php directly?

Comment: You have to intialize FB by javascript dom and then only fb.logout can be used (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/howto/jquery/)

Comment: thanks. Can I put above function inside `$(document).ready(function() {}` this function will be invoked on page load and we want FB.logout to be called on button click.