# signout from facebook session

Tags: php, facebook, session

My login page is 'login.php' if he successfully authenticated then new page is redirect i.e. star.php

I want to keep signout button on start.php. And if user does not click on it, session should be terminated after 15 minutes. Here i tried:

```
    <input type="button" value="logout" onclick="setTimeout();" />

<script>
        var userid;
            FB.init({
            appId: '178812',
            xfbml: true,
            status: true,
            cookie: true,
            });
            FB.getLoginStatus(checkLoginStatus);
        function setTimeout()
        {

            FB.logout(function(response) 
            {
            // user is now logged out
            alert("hi");
            });
        }
 </script>
```

Button click says:

```
ReferenceError: FB is not defined


FB.logout(function(response)
```

**I also want that when user close the browser session should be terminated.**

I dont know whether it is necessary to load JS SDK again on start.php or not

**UPDATE:**

page code:

```
<?php
    $user_id = $_POST['userid'];
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div class = "right"><td style = "width:30%"> <input type="button" value="logout" onclick="setTimeout();" /></td>
        </div>          
    </body> 
    <script>
        var userid;
            FB.init({
            appId: '178812232292862',
            xfbml: true,
            status: true,
            cookie: true,
            });
            FB.getLoginStatus(checkLoginStatus);
        function setTimeout()
        {

            FB.logout(function(response) 
            {
            // user is now logged out
            alert("hi");
            });
        }


    </script>

</html>
```

Comment: are you loading the facebook javascritpt SDK?

Comment: @Fabio: I dont know is it correct or not. Just I tried in this way. Better if without loading SDK

Comment: _"Better if without loading SDK"_ You have to load FB JS SDK!

Comment: Are you using `PHP` or `JS` sdk to authenticate user?

Comment: Duplicate of your own previous question [Facebook signout after 15 minutes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19830358/facebook-signout-after-15-minutes)

Comment: @CBroe: Here I added my try and issue I am facing!

Comment: @AdamAzad: I am using JS sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't included `SJ` SDK

Just add

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

And since you're including `jQuery` I recommend:

```
 $('#logout').click(function () {

     FB.logout(function (response) {
         // user is now logged out
         console.log('Logging You out, Bye Bye!');
       })
 });
```

And it should work [Example!](http://jsfiddle.net/YCFpH/)